# Plotly: How to add quivers to an existing plot?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'd like to add quivers to an existing figure with plotly (python). But the only peace of documentation I could find either create only one quiver ([here](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.figure_factory.create_quiver.html)) or a brand new figure ([there](https://plotly.com/python/quiver-plots/)).

Here's the example on plotly doc :

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

import numpy as np

x,y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 2, .2), np.arange(0, 2, .2))
u = np.cos(x)*y
v = np.sin(x)*y

fig = ff.create_quiver(x, y, u, v)
fig.show()
```

If anyone has a better understanding of plotly that I do, I'd appreciate a lot a few explanations!

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Do you mind to provide the existing figure or a full [mcve](/help/mcve)? It seems to me you could just use `add_trace`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you'd like to add quivers to an existing `ff.create_quiver()` figure, all you have to do is:

1. Create `fig1 = ff.create_quiver(x, y, u, v)`,
2. create another figure with other attributes `fig2 = ff.create_quiver(x, y, u*0.9, v*2)`,
3. and add the resulting `fig2.data` to `fig1` using `fig1.add_traces(data = fig2.data)`

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np

x,y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 2, .2), np.arange(0, 2, .2))
u = np.cos(x)*y
v = np.sin(x)*y

fig1 = ff.create_quiver(x, y, u, v)

fig2 = ff.create_quiver(x, y, u*0.9, v*2)
fig1.add_traces(data = fig2.data)
fig1.show()
```

Comment: Great thanks, it solves the question I asked, not my problem. I'll ask a more precise one. Thanks again!

Comment: @hulyce OK. Thanks for accepting my answer anyway. I'll keep an eye open for what you *really* wanted to achieve.